# How to click and pick div elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok so I want to make so in the profile list, you can click on the profile and it will be highlighted (another background color, lets say yellow). And when you have highlighted this and press "save", somehow i wish to pick the highlighted profiles id and output them.

So my first question:

http://jsfiddle.net/5pZ2v/3/

How can i do something like so you can pick/unpick by clicking/unclicking? And they will be highlighted. And how can i make a selector that grabs these highlighted profile boxes?

Maybe there already exists a function for this or plugin?

Else how can i do this clicking/unclicking to highlight/unhighlight and then output the highlighted element's id attribute in an alert, that appears when you click on a "Show what you choose" button

Comment: you have few mistakes in css, check this .profile{
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

Comment: On your jsfiddle, you're missing a semicolon in the css.  I made a slight update here: http://jsfiddle.net/5pZ2v/2/

Comment: @itsmatt kobe thanks! fixed url in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$('div.profile').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Then use `div.profile.selected` to style the selected profiles in your css. Then when you want to select all the divs that are highlighted just use `$('div.profile.selected')`. If you want to know how many are selected just use `$('div.profile.selected').length`. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/apvqM/

Comment: thanks for your answer! Instead of fadeOut() how can i make an array with all the highlighteds id="" attribute value?

Comment: @Karem I updated my JSFiddle so it outputs an array of all the selected divs' ids now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try .toggleClass()?
i.e. create a css class highlight and add

```
 $("div").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
```

HTH

Ivo Stoykov

PS: Look documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: $("div .your_classname").length will return how many divs have class="your_classname"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the click function of jQuery to mark/unmark a div.

```
 $("div.profile").click(function () {
     // if it's unmarked we mark
     if(!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
          $(this).addClass('selected');
     else
          $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
```

You can then use `each` to get all the marked div :

```
$("div.selected").each(function () {
    // do what you want
});
```

For the boxes not appearing black, it comes from a missing semicolon after the `height` attribute ;)

Comment: I didn't knew the toggleClass() function mentionned by i100, you can use that instead of my first function...

Comment: If i would like to press on button input[name=test], and when i press this i would like to alert how many is highlighted? (has the class) How would i do that?

Comment: You can use `$("input[name=test]").click(function() { alert($(".selected").length); ) });`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/5pZ2v/8/

First you need to give your DIVs an ID then look at my Fiddle.

```
$("div").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});

$('#save-button').click(function(){

    $('#output').html('');                           // clear the output div

    // Loop through each selected div and output it's ID
    $('div.highlight').each(function(){
       $('#output').append('<div>' + $(this).attr('id') + '</div>')
    });
});
```